# How to import my Windows10 KeePass files into Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: windows-10, 18.04

I need to import my Windows10 KeePass files into Ubuntu 18.04 so I can use KePass in Ubuntu without retyping all my passwords, etc....
Thank you
PS I installed Ubuntu for the first time in my life today....

Comment: You just have to save your keepass database file somewhere on Ubuntu and open it with keepass or better keepassx for linux.

Comment: Thanks Bruni. And how do you do that? I have it on a USB drive that I don't see mounted in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Ubuntu!

There are two parts to using KeePass on Ubuntu.  First, you need to install the software.  Within Ubuntu there are two different options here:

- KeePass2 (this is going to look very similar to what you used on windows before, and is also going to have full compatibility with your previous encrypted container)
- KeePassX (this is going to look more like your other Ubuntu applications, and less like a windows program, it will work with your existing encrypted container but may require a conversion step)

Whichever you choose, you need to install it.  Here is how to install KeePass2:

1) Press the super button (windows button) on your keyboard

2) Type term and press enter (this will open up a terminal window for you to type commands)

3) sudo apt update

4) sudo apt install keepass2

Now that KeePass has been installed into Ubuntu, you can use it to open up your old container.  You need to get that container onto this new install using a USB drive, emailing it to yourself, using a network or cloud storage location, etc.  Once the file has been copied onto your new Ubuntu install, just double click on it like normal and KeePass will open it up.

Hope this helps, and once again welcome to Ubuntu!

Comment: Many thanks 64pi0r. Yes emailing myself with the attached doc... I didn't thought about that :) I will deal with that first and later on learn the ways to import all kind of documents from Windows to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

To install keepassX:

open a terminal (ctr. + T) and type

```
sudo apt-get install keepassx
```

To open your database with keepassx. Open keepassX, Database --> open database and navigate to the place you have saved your database file. If you used keepass 1, you need to select import database.

Comment: Thanks Bruni. KeePass was already installed in Ubuntu but my Keepass files were on my Windows10 host. I imported via email as suggested above. Thanks again for helping your reply is also helpful. Best.